# How to initialize HashSet<Long> with values

Tags: java, hashset

How could I initialize a `HashSet<Long>` with predefined values ?

Example:

```java
    HashSet<Long> hsCtr = 
          new HashSet<Long>(Arrays.asList(6557100201,6557100202,6557100203));
```

**Update:**
Just force literals into longs by appending "L"

```java
    HashSet<Long> hsCtr = 
          new HashSet<Long>(Arrays.asList(6557100201L,6557100202L,6557100203L));
```

Thanks

Comment: Force your literals into longs by appending `L`: `Arrays.asList(6557100201L,6557100202L,6557100203L)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The array values should be long, you need to specify explicitly.
Just append l/L to the values inside Arrays.asList(xxxl, xxl, xl);